# proving that a certain function is not differentiable at $(0,0)$

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Let's consider the function given by:
$$
F\left( {x,y} \right) = 
\begin{cases} 
\frac{{xy}}{{\sqrt {x^2  + y^2 } }}\text{ when }\,\,\,\,(x,y) \ne (0,0)
 \\
 \\
 \\
 \\
\,\,\,\,\,\,0\hspace{10ex}\text{ if } \,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,\,(x,y)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
$$

I proved a lot of things of this function, the partial derivated exist everywhere, in particular at $(0,0)$ , But I want to prove that $F$ is not differentiable at $(0,0)$, I I tried by definition but it does not work. Please help me !!

Comment: "I tried by definition but it does not work" can you show your work? It should have worked, if you took the derivatives correctly.

Comment: This has be asked here in the past, the last time wasn't long ago.

Comment: Show how you "tried by definition", and explain what didn't work. That way, we can show you what you overlooked and/or did wrong!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Correct hint**: If you've computed the partial derivatives at $(0,0)$, you know they're both $0$. So, if $f$ were differentiable, you'd have
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{f(x,y)}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=0.$$
Is this so?

Alternatively, if $f$ were differentiable, the directional derivative in every direction $\vec v$ would have to be given by $\nabla f(0,0)\cdot\vec v$.

Comment: Thanks for pointing it out. $+1$